# Elasticsearch Optimizing Query

Tags: elasticsearch

We are implementing search company list using elasticsearch but its not what we expected

```
**Example companies:**      
Infosys technologies        
Infosys technologies ltd        
Infosys technologies pvt ltd        
Infosys technologies Limited        
Infosys technologies Private Limited        
BAC Infosys ltd
```

Scenario:

1. When search the keyword "Infosys" it should return "Infosys
       technologies" list.
2. When search the keyword "Infosys ltd" it should return "Infosys
   technologies" list.
3. When search the keyword "BAC Infosys ltd" it should return "BAC
   Infosys ltd" list.

The below settings and mapping used

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 3,
               "max_gram": 3,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "keyword_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "companies": {
             "properties": {
                 "company_name": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "store": "true",
                     "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                     "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
                     "null_value": "null"
                 }
             }
         }
   }
}
```

Query:

```
{"query":
    {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "match": { "company_name": "Infosys technologies" }}
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": "80%"
      }
    }
}
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a few things both in terms of the search queries and mappings.looking at your scenarios and using your current mappings settings
1) The result will also have BAC value. You should switch to edge n-grams.But this will not allow you to search from between.
2)It also depend what kind of search you are building, you can avoid the arrangement i suggested in 1. for your all scenarios lets assume your list can have BAC value also in the result for scenarios but ranked lower in the list. For this you can use [proximity queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-matching.html) query with fuzzy on for spell checks.

Above three scenarios dont't explain me the whole functionality and uses -cases  for your search feature, but i think proximity search offered by elastic can give you more flexibility to meet your cases.

Comment: Can you give me any example because i am new to Elasticsearch. Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Shingles could help:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shingles.html

For you case the `ng_Gram` analyzer is not pertinent, it should impact performance and relevance score. Create a `shingle filter` and a `custom analyzer` with `standard tokenizer` and `lowercase filter`.

HtH,

Comment: yeah shingles also will help